# ImportError: No module named timeutils

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, django-1.9

I'm trying to follow the install tutorial for Django-celery. After installing, I need to run migrate to make the necessary tables, but this error appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
>
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
>
> line 353, in execute_from_command_line
>
> utility.execute()
>
> File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
>
> line 327, in execute
>
> django.setup()
>
> File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
>
> line 18, in setup
>
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>
> File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>
> line 108, in populate
>
> app_config.import_models(all_models)
>
> File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
>
> line 202, in import_models
>
> self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>
> __import__(name)
>
> File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/models.py",
>
> line 15, in <module>
>
> from celery.utils.timeutils import timedelta_seconds
>
> ImportError: No module named timeutils

I'm not finding anything about this "timeutils" on the Internet...
I'm using Django 1.9.8 and Django-celery 3.1.17.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe this is this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cs.timeutils ?

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/491. If you are using celery 4.0 this is likely the issue, as django-celery does not support this version.

Comment: right, im using celery 4.0... im confused, so i cant use django-celery? When i install the pip package django-celery by default install celery 4.0
How i say to pip install django-celery set a previous version of celery?
In this case, what i do?
tks @elethan

Comment: @GuilhermeRibeirodeSouza my impression is that you must downgrade to an older version of celery if you want to use django-celery, but I am not 100% sure as I have never used celery.

Comment: @elethan, yes i think the same, but downgrade to an older version of celery looks like a hard work because i not finding anything how to downgrade the package of celery.

Comment: Try the following and let me know if it works: `pip install celery==3.1`

Comment: thanks @elethan. I did `pip uninstall celery` after this `pip install celery==3.1` and worked! :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It appears that `django-celery==3.1.17` does not work with newer versions of `celery` (see [this github issue](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/491)).

If it is acceptable to you to use an earlier version of `celery`, you can uninstall your current version, install a specific older version, and `django-celery` should work again. For example:

```
$ pip uninstall celery
$ pip install celery==3.1
```

should get things working again until `django-celery` supports a newer version of `celery`.

Answer (score 2):

For Django==1.9.8

```
$ pip install django-celery==3.1.17
$ pip uninstall celery
$ pip install celery==3.1.25
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but this helped me, pip3 did the trick for me, I needed the latest version of django-celery for my project so I put this in my requirements.txt file (at the time of writing this the latest version was django-celery==3.3.1)

```
celery==
croniter==
django-celery==3.3.1
django-celery-beat==
kombu==
```

and then run the command

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

which automatically checked for the dependency of the various packages and installed all other packages, I then run pip freeze and got

```
celery==3.1.26.post2
croniter==1.0.15
django-celery==3.3.1
django-celery-beat==2.0.0
kombu==3.0.37
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed django-celery
```

Worked for me